# Unwanted Extra Scroll Space with Fixed div in Safari WKWebView on iOS 13

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, wkwebview

I have a simple HTML page where there is a `position:fixed` toolbar at the bottom and an editable text space (a `contenteditable` `div`) above it. When viewed in iOS Safari on iOS 13, when you tap into the editable part of the screen, the "fixed" toolbar below becomes scrollable and I now have two scroll bars on the page. I also now have heartburn.

I want the "fixed" toolbar to stay put and **not scroll** because of the keyboard.

[image]

Any idea how I can do this? Here's the full code of the sample page: https://jsfiddle.net/ermwf1n7/

Or you can view the whole page on an iPhone here: http://labrum.co/scroll.html

Here's the code itself:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <style type="text/css">
    #scrolly{
      padding-bottom:55px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      outline:none;
    }
    #fixed{
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      height:55px;
      background:#333;
      text-align: center;
      color:#CCC;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="scrolly" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, harum accusantium esse voluptatibus aspernatur fugit rem, vero quaerat quos dolores neque cumque temporibus cum! Excepturi omnis molestias sit cumque in.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, harum accusantium esse voluptatibus aspernatur fugit rem, vero quaerat quos dolores neque cumque temporibus cum! Excepturi omnis molestias sit cumque in.</p>
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="fixed">
    Fixed
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm managing this in a `WKWebView` so I can make the bottom of the `webView` be constrained to the top of the keyboard, but once the keyboard appears, the scroll situation gets crazy.

Any idea how I can fix this either on the iOS/Swift side or the HTML/CSS/JS side?

Comment: Hello Clifton, having the same issue here and none of the methods found on stackoverflow worked for me...have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't think there is a way around it. It's just the way iOS Safari behaves. 

Comment: Ok man, thanks. If I will find something i will come here with an update.